# custom view not working when declared in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-view

I've an app where it's activity has an inner class that extends view. the view class displays a bitmap and it all works fine. What i'm trying to do now is place a button on the view that diaplays tha bitmap. to do this i made the original inner class TouchView a seperate class. i then declared it in an xml file in the layout folder inside a relelative layout and beneath a button. this i thought would give there appearance of the button floating on top of the view. i'm getting the following error. does anyone know why? thanks

```
05-09 11:45:22.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12211): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-09 11:45:22.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12211): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 11:45:22.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12211):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:954)
05-09 11:45:22.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12211):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:980)
05-09 11:45:22.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12211):     at com.tecmark.TouchView.onDraw(TouchView.java:172)
05-09 11:45:22.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12211):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
```

Code:

```
public class Jjilapp extends Activity {



    private static final String TAG = "*********jjil";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside oncreate about to set contentview = ");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.touchview);


    }


}
```

enter code here

```
class TouchView extends View{


    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap whitebm;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private int centreX = 1;
    private int centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;





    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
    }

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

       .........code that gets bitmap and changes it 





}// end of touchView constructor


    public void changePixel(){  


        for (int i=0; i < bgr.getWidth(); ++i) {
            for (int y=0; y < bgr.getHeight(); ++y) {

    if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centreX, 2) + ( Math.pow(y - centreY, 2) ) ) <= radius ){

                    bgr.setPixel(i,y,Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                }
            }
        }   

        }// end of changePixel()


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        ......code for touch events
    }//end of onTouchEvent


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(whitebm, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(centreX, centreY, radius,pTouch);


    }//end of onDraw


}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill">


   <Button android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

  <com.tecmark.TouchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> 


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added the activity to your manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your both constructor to this

```
public TouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    TouchView(context, null);
}

public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context,attr);

   .........code that gets bitmap and changes it 

}// end of touchView constructor
```

Change you xml to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill">

    <com.tecmark.TouchView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @TOX1C hey thank alot! i had to comment out a line in your first constructor to this. public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // TouchView(context, null);
    }
does it make a diifernce?

Comment: no unless you are not creating touchView from code but why you want to comment it? nad check updated answer

Comment: @TOX1C Actually just looking at it, the button doesn't float above the TouchView view, rather it's at the top of the screen. before touchview was set to fullsreen mode, it seem to be shortened now to allow for the button. is there a way to make it float above the view? this is why i put it in relative layout as i thought preceeding node would seem to float. thats the characteristic i'd like.

Comment: @TOX1C nice one, so if you put the view first in the layout then subsequent children will float? thanks again.

Comment: Just remember you can findViewById until you setContentView(R.layout.main); I just spent half an hour realizing that..